# Not able to load HTML file from assets folder

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am trying to get data from an HTML file placed in my assets folder. Though on every call, I receives an error in the browser console.

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/TreeStructure/manual_testing/what_is_manual_testing.html", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html lang="en">
↵<head>
↵  <titl…↵    </div>
↵  </div>
↵</div>
↵</body>
↵</html>
↵"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/assets/TreeStructure/manual_testing/what_is_manual_testing.html"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/TreeStructure/manual_testing/what_is_manual_testing.html"
```

I am trying to get the HTML content using following code

```
public getPageContent(path: string) {
    return this.http.get('assets/TreeStructure/' + path + '.html');
  }
```

My complete code can be found here -

> https://github.com/vibhorgoyal18/atest-blog

Comment: Have you set up your CORS to be able to serve files from a local source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the call expects JSON data; not HTML. You get an error that says exactly that:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Currently (until Angular Ivy is released) you can't load HTML and show it dynamically. So, you need to rethink how to do what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Thanks, I got a workaround. I am catching the error and loading error.error.text in my page. Not a good way, but that works for now.